# How does one use the new "rails new myapp --api" with a client-side JavaScript framework?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I apologize if this is a stupid question, but I don't understand the fundamentals of using [JSON in accordance with a JavaScript framework in Rails 5.0](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2016/6/30/Rails-5-0-final/#api-mode):

> Rails is not only a great choice when you want to build a full-stack
>   application that uses server-side rendering of HTML templates, but
>   also a great companion for the new crop of client-side JavaScript or
>   native applications that just needs the backend to speak JSON. We’ve
>   made this even clearer now with the new –api mode. If you create a new
>   Rails application using rails new backend --api, you’ll get a slimmed
>   down skeleton and configuration that assumes you’ll be working with
>   JSON, not HTML.

React seems to be favored by many, so I want to learn how to use it with a Rails backend. To build the hashes I'm leaning toward using Jbuilder.

My main confusion is how to build a layout without an `.html.erb` view. If I only have two files, one `.json.jbuilder`, one `.js.jsx` — how do I call the React components? Or does every controller method need three corresponding views? Or am I just missing the point of `--api` entirely?

Comment: I have not tried this api concept yet. If it is what I guess, then its like your javascript framework will send request to this rails app in backend to get the data from database. So this concept creates a trimmed down rails app without JS , layout and other not required things and only send the JSON data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.json.jbuilder` files are used to format the response from the server. In an API application, they serve exactly the same core purpose as the views in a standard MVC application - they expose data. In the case with API apps, the data is in JSON format and it can be accessed via endpoint.

With API apps, you have a clear separation between back-end logic and front-end logic. They are two separate apps which have an interface through which they communicate. You don't need a React app or any other front-end app to see the data, you can access an endpoint using a tool such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to see what each endpoint in your Rails app returns.

React steps in when you want to build an interface that will use the endpoints of your API app and display the data. This is where React, with its `.js.jsx` components, steps in.

[Have a look at the source code of a React-Rails app I've built](https://github.com/Kaizeras/react-rails-tutorial). It's not a standard API app, but it's built on the same idea:

[Here](https://github.com/Kaizeras/react-rails-tutorial/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/components/_body.js.jsx) you can see how the `componentDidMount()`  function makes a $http request to the items endpoint in React

```
React.createClass({
getInitialState() {
    return { items: [] }
},


componentDidMount() {
    $.getJSON('/api/v1/items.json', (response) => { this.setState({ items: response }) });
},
```

And [here](https://github.com/Kaizeras/react-rails-tutorial/blob/master/app/controllers/api/v1/items_controller.rb) you can see what the server returns to that endpoint.

```
  def index
    respond_with Item.all
  end
```

With a standard API app, the controller syntax might be a little bit different, and there would be a `.json.jbuilder` files that would let me format the response, but the general idea is the same.

If you'd like to get a better idea of the concept, have a look at my  [tutorial](http://tutorials.pluralsight.com/ruby-ruby-on-rails/building-a-crud-interface-with-react-and-ruby-on-rails) on the topic.

Comment: Your tutorial is very helpful. What I can't figure out is how one should handle many `GET` requests. Since all the "data handling" (`GET` is just setting instance variables mostly) is in the API namespace, and you only use `<%= react_component 'Main' %>` in `site/index.html.erb`, how do you "tell" React to respond to routes without using other views and components?